# Dealing with Core data one-to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, tableview

I have been beating my head over this issue for some time now and my last hope is Stack Overflow.

Here is the app idea. I have two entities modeled in core data. The `Golfer` entity has a one to many relationship with `FittingSession`, so each golfer is capable of having more than one fitting session. I am not able to post an image for the data models as I am a new user.
But here are the details:

ENTITY: GOLFER and FITTING SESSION
Attributes for Golfer - first_name, last_name, emailId, contactNum, picture
Relationship : NSSet * fittingSessions

Attributes for Fitting Sessions - session_number, date, location, notes.
Relationship: Golfer * whoPlayed

I am working on one view controller called ViewManager (kinda base view for all my classes) and it has 2-3 Custom `UIView`s inside it. I animate them in and out whenever I need them.

I am getting my Golfers list-collection in a tableview from `NSFetchedResultsController` and getting the Fitting Sessions attributes in a tableview by the same technique using `NSFetchedResultsController`. My question is: How do I get a specific fitting session for a specific golfer? What do I have to write in TableViewDidSelectRow Method of Parent( Golfer )View? How do I deal with this one to many relationship? Here's my code:

```
     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        if(tableView == mGolferTblView)
        {
            NSInteger count = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
            NSLog(@"count section GOLFER TABLE VIEW=%d", count);
            return count; 
        }

        else if(tableView == mFittingTblView)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else {

        }

        return 0;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(tableView == mGolferTblView)
        {
            id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
            NSLog(@"count for array ROWS for GOLFERS =%d", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
            return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        }

        else if(tableView == mFittingTblView)
        {


 mFittingSessionArray = [mFittingSessionSet allObjects];

    NSLog(@"array here is=%@", mFittingSessionArray);

    NSLog(@"count for ROWS in FITTING SESSIONS table view=%d", [mFittingSessionArray count]);
    return [mFittingSessionArray count];



    //        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fittingFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    //        NSLog(@"count for array ROWS for FITTING SESSIONS =%d", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
    //        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

        }
        else {

        }

        return 0;

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(tableView == mGolferTblView)
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            static NSInteger fullNameTag = 1;
            static NSInteger imageTag = 2;

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

                UILabel *fakeLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 30, 100, 30)];
                fakeLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                fakeLbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                fakeLbl.text=@"3 days ago";
                [cell.contentView addSubview:fakeLbl];
                [fakeLbl release];

                UIImageView *btnImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 40, 25, 28)];
                btnImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_25x28.png"];
                btnImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:btnImage];
                [btnImage release];

                UILabel *fullNameLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 300, 30)];
                fullNameLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                fullNameLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                fullNameLbl.numberOfLines = 1;
                fullNameLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                fullNameLbl.tag = fullNameTag;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:fullNameLbl];
                [fullNameLbl release];

                UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 71, 91)];
                imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                imageView.tag = imageTag;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
                [imageView release];
            }


            mGolfer = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            UILabel * fullNameLbl = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:fullNameTag];
            fullNameLbl.text =  mGolfer.fullName;

            UIImageView * imgView = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:imageTag];
            imgView.image = mGolfer.picture;

            return  cell;
        }

        if(tableView == mFittingTblView)
        {        
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            static NSInteger locationTag = 1;
            static NSInteger notesTag = 2;

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

                UIImageView *iconImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 11, 18)];
                iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_locationmarker_11x18.png"];
                iconImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
                [iconImage release];

                UILabel *fakeDateLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 15, 100, 20)];
                fakeDateLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                fakeDateLbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                fakeDateLbl.text=@"apr.30.2012";
                [cell.contentView addSubview:fakeDateLbl];
                [fakeDateLbl release];

                UIImageView *fakeImage1 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 90, 43, 43)];
                fakeImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_catDriver_43x43.png"];
                fakeImage1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:fakeImage1];
                [fakeImage1 release];

                UIImageView *fakeImage2 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 90, 43, 43)];
                fakeImage2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_catFairway_43x43.png"];
                fakeImage2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:fakeImage2];
                [fakeImage2 release];

                UIImageView *fakeImage3 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 90, 43, 43)];
                fakeImage3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_catHybrid_43x43.png"];
                fakeImage3.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:fakeImage3];
                [fakeImage3 release];

                UIImageView *fakeImage4 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 90, 43, 43)];
                fakeImage4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_catIron_43x43.png"];
                fakeImage4.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:fakeImage4];
                [fakeImage4 release];

                UIImageView *fakeImage5 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(205, 90, 43, 43)];
                fakeImage5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_catWedge_43x43.png"];
                fakeImage5.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:fakeImage5];
                [fakeImage5 release];

                UILabel *sessionLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 150, 30)];
                sessionLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                sessionLbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
                sessionLbl.text = @"session";
                sessionLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:sessionLbl];
                [sessionLbl release];

                UILabel *locationLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 32, 270, 30)];
                locationLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                locationLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                locationLbl.tag = locationTag;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:locationLbl];
                [locationLbl release];

                UILabel *notesLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 54, 270, 30)];
                notesLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                notesLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                notesLbl.tag = notesTag;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:notesLbl];
                [notesLbl release];


            }

            mFittingSessionArray = [mFittingSessionSet allObjects];

            mFittingSession = [mFittingSessionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            UILabel *locationLbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:locationTag];
            locationLbl.text = mFittingSession.locationUppercase;
            NSLog(@"location=%@", mFittingSession.locationUppercase);

            UILabel *notesLbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:notesTag];
            notesLbl.text = mFittingSession.notesInQuotes;

            return  cell;

        }
        return 0;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {    
        if(tableView == mGolferTblView)
        {

            mGolfer = (Golfer *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            mGolferNameLbl.text = mGolfer.fullName;
            mGolferHeaderPicture.image = mGolfer.picture;

            NSSet * fittingSessionSet = mGolfer.fittingSessions;

            mFittingSessionArray = [fittingSessionSet allObjects];

            NSLog(@"count for sessions=%d", [mFittingSessionArray count]);
            NSLog(@"fiting sessions for golfer %@ are= %@", mGolfer.first_name, mFittingSessionArray);
    }
    }
```

Also, this is how I add a new fitting session to a particular golfer:

```
  - (IBAction)addNewSession:(id)sender
    {


        AppDelegate * applicationDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSManagedObjectContext * context = [applicationDelegate managedObjectContext];

        mFittingSession=(FittingSession*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FittingSession" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        mFittingSession.location=mLocationTextField.text;
        mFittingSession.notes=mNotesTxtView.text;
        **mFittingSession.whoPlayed = self.golfer;** This is setting the relationship (whoPlayed is inverse relation to golfer provided by core data)
}
```

Please help me in this as I am really not getting how to deal with the relationship in core data. Please provide some code or snippets so that I can know what's going on.

Thank you

Comment: Its been a day and nobody has responded back. Can anybody please have a look and respond. I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(tableView == mGolferTblView)
    {
        NSInteger count = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
        NSLog(@"count section GOLFER TABLE VIEW=%d", count);
        return count; 
    }

    else if(tableView == mFittingTblView)
    {
        NSInteger countOfSections = 1;
        NSLog(@"count section FITTING SESSION VIEW=%d", countOfSections);
        return countOfSections;
    }
    else {

    }

    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == mGolferTblView)
    {
        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        NSLog(@"count for ROWS in GOLFERS table view =%d", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

    else if(tableView == mFittingTblView)
    {
        mFittingSessionArray = [mFittingSessionSet allObjects];

        NSLog(@"array here is=%@", mFittingSessionArray);

        NSLog(@"count for ROWS in FITTING SESSIONS table view=%d", [mFittingSessionArray count]);
        return [mFittingSessionArray count];
    }
    else {

    }

    return 0;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == mGolferTblView)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        static NSInteger fullNameTag = 1;
        static NSInteger imageTag = 2;

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;


            UILabel *fullNameLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 300, 30)];
            fullNameLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            fullNameLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            fullNameLbl.numberOfLines = 1;
            fullNameLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            fullNameLbl.tag = fullNameTag;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:fullNameLbl];
            [fullNameLbl release];

            UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 71, 91)];
            imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            imageView.tag = imageTag;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];
        }


        mGolfer = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        UILabel * fullNameLbl = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:fullNameTag];
        fullNameLbl.text =  mGolfer.fullName;

        UIImageView * imgView = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:imageTag];
        imgView.image = mGolfer.picture;

        return  cell;
    }

    else if(tableView == mFittingTblView)
    {  
        **mFittingSessionArray = [mFittingSessionSet allObjects];** // Added this line

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        static NSInteger locationTag = 1;
        static NSInteger notesTag = 2;

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

            UILabel *locationLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 32, 270, 30)];
            locationLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            locationLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            locationLbl.tag = locationTag;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:locationLbl];
            [locationLbl release];

            UILabel *notesLbl =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 54, 270, 30)];
            notesLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            notesLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            notesLbl.tag = notesTag;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:notesLbl];
            [notesLbl release];
        }

        mFittingSession = [mFittingSessionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *locationLbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:locationTag];
        UILabel *notesLbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:notesTag];

        locationLbl.text = mFittingSession.locationUppercase;
        notesLbl.text = mFittingSession.notesInQuotes;

        return  cell;

    }
    else {

    }
    return 0;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if(tableView == mGolferTblView)
    {
        if(self.editing)
        {
            [self.golferTblView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut

                             animations:^ {

                                 mEditGolfersView.hidden = NO;
                                 mEditGolfersView.frame = CGRectMake(305, mEditGolfersView.frame.origin.y, mEditGolfersView.frame.size.width, mEditGolfersView.frame.size.height);
                             }

                             completion:NULL];

            mGolfer = (Golfer *) [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            mEditFirstName.text = mGolfer.first_name;
            mEditMiddleName.text = mGolfer.middle_name;
            mEditLastName.text = mGolfer.last_name;
            mEditEmailField.text = mGolfer.email_id;
            mEditContactNum.text = mGolfer.contactNumber;
            mEditPictureView.image = mGolfer.picture;

            mShowDataBtn.enabled = NO;

            return;
        }

        [self.golferTblView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut

                         animations:^ {

                             mGolfersView.frame = CGRectMake(-260, mGolfersView.frame.origin.y, mGolfersView.frame.size.width, mGolfersView.frame.size.height);
                         }

                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             mGolfersView.hidden = YES;
                         }];



        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn

                         animations:^ {

                             mFittingSessionView.hidden = NO;
                             mFittingSessionView.frame = CGRectMake(-19, mFittingSessionView.frame.origin.y, mFittingSessionView.frame.size.width, mFittingSessionView.frame.size.height);
                         }

                         completion:NULL];

        mGolfer = (Golfer *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        mGolferNameLbl.text = mGolfer.fullName;
        mGolferHeaderPicture.image = mGolfer.picture;
        mFittingSessionSet = mGolfer.fittingSessions;

        mFittingSessionArray = [mFittingSessionSet allObjects];

        NSLog(@"count for sessions=%d", [mFittingSessionArray count]);
        NSLog(@"fiting sessions for golfer %@ are= %@", mGolfer.first_name, mFittingSessionArray);

        **[mFittingTblView reloadData];** // Added this and this reloads the data for fitting view.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question correctly, but to get a Golfer's Fitting Session is really easy. So in the first code block you just do the following:

```
mGolfer = (Golfer *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSSet *fittingSession = mGolfer.fittingSessions;
```

You can access the relations as you would access the other attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.You got my question right.I am trying to get a specific golfer's fitting session by clicking on that tableview did select row. i did that already and see my edited code. I think my predicate is not working correctly. Can you look over please?

Comment: You cannot query a relation like you do in your predicate. But why are you using 2 FetchedResultsControllers? I think you don't need a FetchedResultController for the Fitting Sessions. Here's what I would do: 1. When user selects Golfer from List, get the Golfer's Fitting Sessions like I described. 2. Transform the NSSet into an NSArray and use that to feed the Fitting Sessions TableView.

Comment: I need to fill my Fitting Session Table view also with session information(location , notes etc.) How will I fill and save information(data) in my Fitting Session TableView? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: In the above code I wrote, what would be the best way to use Predicate? I see the console, when I tap the golfer, it gives the right fitting sessions for it. But it displays nothing in the Fitting sessions TableView. My predicate is definitely wrong. What shall I use to get the fitting sessions for a particular golfer. I thought i was pretty close to the solution.

Comment: In your Fittings Array you have all the information you need. Each Fittings element in that Array is of type FittingSession, so it contains all the attributes of a session. You're method to add a session looks correct, but you forgot to save the context after adding a new session.

Comment: @predicate You don't need the predicate if you already have the Golfer. You just get a Golfer's sessions by calling Golfer.fittingSessions. The NSSet contains all the FittingSessions objects that have a relation to the Golfer.

Comment: Oh I need to save the context too. I didn't know that here. I always saved the context in other cases. My bad! what predicate shall I use here to get it working? Any idea?

Comment: Oh Alright. So in Fitting session fetched results controller, I don't need a predicate? If I don't add a predicate, what I see is fitting sessions for golfers for whom I didn't even add a fitting session. Although when I check the console, it shows me right info. but the fitting table view still displays everything even if there are no sessions for golfer.

Comment: You don't need a FetchedResultsController for the Fittings TableView! Just use the Fittings Array that you get from the Golfer and display that in a "normal" UITableView. You only need a FetchedResultsController when you retrieve your data directly from CoreData. For a golfer's sessions you don't need to do that, because you've already fetched the Golfer from CoreData and the Golfer "contains" all it's sessions. So you already have the Sessions when you have the Golfer. No need for a new Fetch.

Comment: So, I did save the context, removed the predicate as you said, I am facing the problem I mentioned in my above comment. Shall I remove all the code for fitting session fetched results controller..as you told me I don't need that.

Comment: I will try what you said. I am really thankful to you for your help and I wish I get that to work.Please keep checking my post, I am new to core data and I might need your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Just remove all the NSFetchedResultController stuff from your setting UITableView and use it in the "normal" way by adding a datasource to it an implement the DataSource methods with the content of the Golfer's FittingSessions Array. Good luck!

Comment: Joern, Now I have the mFittingSessionArray which I get from the NSSet * fittingSessionSet = mGolfer.fittingSessions. I have : mFittingSessionArray = [fittingSessionSet allObjects]; All good here. I want to add a new session from a Create Session View which has location and notes textfields. So, In my above method for addNewSession, I am not using NSManagedContext anymore. How will I ad my new session now? lil confused ! To which array shall I add all the objects created from a session view?

Comment: Actually no, I do need the NSManagedContext. That's fine.

Comment: Can u see my edited code please? I have both the golfers and fitting sessions table views inside the same view. The fittingSessionArray count is always 0. Have a look please at the edited code and let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I am very close now to get it done. The problem is it's displaying the wrong fitting sessions for a golfer. I have edited the code. I am not able to figure out the issue. Please get back to me.

Comment: Finally, I solved it. It's working perfect. I have edited the code. But I feel it's not the perfect way to do. Like it's not the best way. I would really like to have your opinion as implementing in a smart way and best way is good programming. Please have a look when you have time and respond back. Appreciate your help! It wasn't possible without your help! cheers

Comment: Glad you solved it. Looks good to me. The only thing you might want to change: As I understand you use mFittingSessionSet as a property and the get an NSArray from that everytime when you have to build a cell for the FittingSessions TableView. You might want to use an NSArray to store the array when the user selects a Golfer, so that you do not have to transform the NSSet into an NSArray for every single cell. Apart from that it looks ok.

Comment: One final thing (because you are new to Stack Overflow): Can you please accept my answer by clicking on the hollow checkmark on the top left of the answer? When you do that, the question will be closed and I get awarded some reputation points for helping you out. Thanks and good luck with your project!

Comment: I did that. There is one more thing. I need to add a search bar in Golfer's table view also. Do I need a separate NSFetchedResultsController for that? I can't use SearchDisplayController because my golfer table view is a subview inside a view. When I use SearchDisplayController and try to search for a particular golfer, it gives the results in a tableview equivalent to the size of the whole view and not according to the size of my table view. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Joern, Also I am trying to follow what are your saying about using an NSArray to store the array when the user selects a golfer. I tried storing in NSUserDefaults, it don't work. How do we store the array then?